# What is the difference in floor function and truncate function?

Tags: math

What is the difference between Math.Floor() and Math.Truncate() in .NET?

For example, Math.Floor(4.4) = 4 Math.Truncate(4.4) = 4.

Comment: Any chance you checked the .net documentation first?

Answer (score 2):

These function behave differently for negative numbers.

`Math.Truncate(-4.5) = -4`

`Math.Floor(-4.5) = -5`

Answer (score -1):

Math.Floor rounds down Math.Ceiling rounds up and Math.Truncate rounds towards zero. Thus, Math.Truncate is like Math.Floor for positive numbers, and like Math.Ceiling for negative numbers.

Comment: Copying from a different answer without reference is no good style